# Using CEC to turn on and off TV

Tags: linux, display, hdmi

I am working on a project where we need a monitor that can be turned on and off automatically.

For this to happen I thought of using a linux box (more specific a Raspberry Pi) with a HDMI-CEC connection to the TV, and then some cron job that turns the TV on and off at specified times.

But then I wonder.. Will this be possible?

And.. Any other suggestions for how to accomplish the goal of a monitor that automatically turns on and off?

Answer (score 1):

I have about 8 machines at work that I use for digital signage displays.  I turn them off at 10pm, and back on at 6:45am, using DPMS with `xset`.  Just two cron-jobs:

```
45 6 * * * root su <user who is auto-logged into the gui> -c "xset -display :0 dpms force on"

0 22 * * * root su <user who is auto-logged into the gui> -c "xset -display :0 dpms force off"
```

Of course, this only works if the computer is providing whatever is being displayed on the monitor.

Comment: Does all monitors support DPMS, or is it only some specific ones?
Otherwise nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are other solutions as well.  Using a simple [analog](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Defiant-15-Amp-24-Hour-Plug-In-Mechanical-Big-Button-Timer-49810DI/203678109?N=5yc1vZc334) or [digital](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Defiant-15-Amp-7-Day-Plug-In-Digital-Polarized-Timer-49809/203678107) timer would work.  There are home automation solutions, like [X10](http://www.x10.com/), that are programmable.